# When can I claim the Foreign Earned Income Tax Exclusion / ask employer to stop withholding?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, tax-deduction, foreign-income

I've decided to stay abroad for a year (abroad starting August 1, 2020) and am considering taking the foreign earned income exclusion. If I decide to go that route, when should I have my employer stop withholding income tax?

My concern is that by April 15, 2021, I will not yet have been out of the country for 11 months.

Does that mean I can only claim the exemption, and get a refund, the following year (in 2022)? Or, in April 2021, can I say "I'm on track to be out of the country until July" and still take the exemption / have my employer stop withholding now?

What if I file for an extension and pay in October 2021, does that make a difference?

If the tax filing deadline is again pushed to July in 2021, would I then be in the clear to stop withholding now?

## Edit

I'll be using the physical presence test, not the bona fide resident test (I won't be staying in a single country). The employer is US based (which still counts as foreign earned income): https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/foreign-earned-income-exclusion-what-is-foreign-earned-income

Comment: Please tell us the country in which will be earning the foreign income and whether your employer is in that country or not. As a US citizen, you are required to report on your tax return your world-wide income and pay income tax to the US on your world-wide income regardless of whether you have paid tax on it in other countries. The Foreign Earned Income Tax Exclusion simply says that if you are _earning_ income in a foreign country, you can exclude that income (up to a limit) from taxable income for the US. It does not say that the foreign country cannot tax you on the income you earn abroad,

Comment: My location doesn't matter, as I'l be using the "Physical presence test", not the "bona fide resident" test. The employer is in the US but it still qualifies as foreign earned income: "For example, income you receive for work done in France is income from a foreign source even if the income is paid directly to your bank account in the United States and your employer is in New York City." https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/foreign-earned-income-exclusion-what-is-foreign-earned-income